# Antiderivative of general exponential function on complex field

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we define antiderivative of $a^z$ ($a$ is a complex number) in complex field? Is it similar with how it works in real numbers?

Comment: Well, not quite.  First, one needs to define a branch of the logarithm for $\log(a)$.  Then, all is the same.